# coding watson conversation for complex inputs?

Tags: javascript, python, api, watson-conversation

I would like to know how can I integrate some coding (python or javascript) in my dialog, in order to avoid the very limited bluemix interface for example for loops, or text mining.

EX : I am creating a pizza chatbot and I need to be able to process this kind of request :

`I would like 2 margarita whose one with extra cheese and the other with pepperoni and a regina, with 3  diet cokes and two beers`

It is just impossible to do it with bluemix.

If anyone has a solution I would be very grateful.
Thanks

Comment: Have you checked out the toolkits and SDKs for Watson Conversation? You can perform pre- and post-processing of input, use NLU service and others to annotate and augment the input, pass variables in and out of the dialog processing.

Answer (score 0):

So the first thing to understand is that Conversation has good and bad use cases.

If your user can enter in structured data, then it is better to use a form. Be that in the conversation window (like Watson Virtual Agent), or a form on your site/app.

So your example doesn't look like a good use case.

---

That said...

With your example it's possible if your main items are entities, and you haver `@sys-number` system entity enabled. You can then check the `entities` array to see distance from each other.

**Example**

Created the following entities.

```
@PizzaType
@PizzaTopping
@Drinks
```

When I ask your question, the `entities` object returns the following:

```
    [
  {
    "entity": "Drinks",
    "location": [
      104,
      114
    ],
    "value": "diet coke",
    "confidence": 1
  },
  {
    "entity": "PizzaType",
    "location": [
      72,
      81
    ],
    "value": "Pepperoni",
    "confidence": 1
  },
  {
    "entity": "Drinks",
    "location": [
      123,
      128
    ],
    "value": "beer",
    "confidence": 1
  },
  {
    "entity": "PizzaType",
    "location": [
      88,
      94
    ],
    "value": "Regina",
    "confidence": 1
  },
  {
    "entity": "PizzaTopping",
    "location": [
      46,
      52
    ],
    "value": "cheese",
    "confidence": 1
  },
  {
    "entity": "PizzaType",
    "location": [
      15,
      24
    ],
    "value": "Margarita",
    "confidence": 1
  },
  {
    "entity": "sys-number",
    "location": [
      13,
      14
    ],
    "value": "2",
    "confidence": 1,
    "metadata": {
      "numeric_value": 2
    }
  },
  {
    "entity": "sys-number",
    "location": [
      31,
      34
    ],
    "value": "1",
    "confidence": 1,
    "metadata": {
      "numeric_value": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "entity": "sys-number",
    "location": [
      101,
      102
    ],
    "value": "3",
    "confidence": 1,
    "metadata": {
      "numeric_value": 3
    }
  },
  {
    "entity": "sys-number",
    "location": [
      119,
      122
    ],
    "value": "2",
    "confidence": 1,
    "metadata": {
      "numeric_value": 2
    }
  }
]
```

A summary of that is:

[image]

You can see straight away there are some issues there. If the user doesn't mention a number, you have to account for that. Also something like this question would break it as well (unless you cater for it).

```
I would like margarita pizzas (two).
```

But the important point is to build your system with representative questions. Your example question may never be asked by an end user, or you can even shape the conversation to prevent such an input.